# WPF window and element focus

Tags: wpf

I've got a WPF form inside a window and a short series of events like this:

1) 1st form has series of selection buttons
2) Clicking a button brings up a progress bar window over the existing window
3) Progress window closes and 1st form switches to a new 2nd form using page navigation

The problem is that the 2nd form (and the entire window) no longer has any focus and what's really killing me is that the window is no longer getting OnKeyDown() calls (it's still the top winow). If I hit the tab key the first menu option is highlighted and the following key stroke will fire a OnKeyDown(). Also, if I alt-tab to another app and then alt-tab back to my window it will begin receiving OnKeyDown() again.

How do I figure out where the focus is after the dialog?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using navigation then the focus will have switched to the Page that you have navigated to, assuming that it is Focusable.

You can check that by setting up a breakpoint in a Focused event handle for the Page.

Alternatively you can use an explicit control.SetFocus() in the page.Navigated handler.